# delay in as3 while loop

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am using as3.  My sprites are not working correctly on hittestpoint in a while loop.  I think this is because it is going too fast before it can update the display.  So I would like to add a delay to the while loop.  What is the easiest way to do this?

Like:

```
while (condition){
MAIN CODE HERE    
CODE FOR DELAY OF 20ms    
}
```

How can I do a delay in as3?

Comment: can you further explain the problem and include some code?  it seems like there should be a better solution instead of delaying the main thread.

Comment: The main code is just a moving shape.  Nothing special at the moment.  I need the moving to take place in steps.  I could use enterframe but would like to keep it in main code and take 10 moves down on a mouse click, but slowly with 1 step every second or so.

Comment: If there is need to delay, you need next frame. Delaying user code will achieve nothing - system code executes only after user code, not in parallel. Use ENTER_FRAME or Timer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a [Timer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html) instead of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

or a recursive function with some delay built in:
I normally use the TweenLite library for a lot of things including things like you´re trying to do..

something like that:

import com.greensock.TweenLite;

recurse();

function recurse():void{

yourCodeHere;

TweenLite.delayedCall(0.02, recurse);

}

Comment: Thank you very much Drala !  I didn't knew there was such a function in TweenLite !